# change the equations fonts automatically

Tags: fonts, formatting, font-encodings

In my document, I have several equations. What I need is to change their font automatically to mathrm. I can change each equation separately (\mathrm{....}), but this will be so tedious for me. So how can I change the font of all the equations in the meantime?

To be more precisely, When I wrote for example:

```
\begin{equation}
x=\gamma*4
\end{equation}
```

The equation seems to be written in Italic. What I want is to have all the equations shown in mathrm.  Otherwise, what is the best font to write an equation?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Hello, just I want to change the font of all my equations to mathrm. Is ti possible with latex ? Can I find a package specific for mathrm ?

Comment: Do you mean upright characters, which should be formatted in the same serif font you use in the rest of the document?

Comment: @Christina I understood that; I just don't understand the reason why you want it. Math variables in italics is a normal typographic device for better emphasizing them from the context.

Comment: @Christina there is a ortotypographical reason for typeset maths in italics, meanwhile functions and operators are typesetted in roman. As egreg I don't know why you want to change it. Could you explain better the question?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @Christina Maybe you should use a different font for maths, maybe [Euler vm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eulervm) that has a more vertical stroke. Anyway, maybe you should try to read [this book](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/notaciones_cientificas.html) could be useful for doubts like this one.

Comment: In fact, I used first the palatino font, but I would like to change it to a better font

Comment: Have a look at the `mathastext` package.

Answer (score 2):

The [mathastext](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package may do what you're looking for. The package's user guide states that

> `mathastext`'s basic aim is to have the same font for text and mathematics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
$x=\gamma*4$
\end{document}
```